# How to change Docker daemon's arguments in OSX

Tags: macos, docker

I need to modify the docker daemon'a arguments in OSX.

I got an error when pull a private repository without certificate.

> 2014/11/11 13:40:02 Error: Invalid registry endpoint
>   https://registry.af-sys.com/v1/: Get
>   https://registry.af-sys.com/v1/_ping: dial tcp 54.229.102.95:443: i/o
>   timeout. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an
>   unknown CA certificate, **please add `--insecure-registry
>   registry.af-sys.com` to the daemon's arguments**. In the case of HTTPS,
>   if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the
>   flag; simply place the CA certificate at
>   /etc/docker/certs.d/registry.af-sys.com/ca.crt

According to this message I should modify the daemon arguments. How can I do that?

Comment: Right now I'm changing the init script (/etc/init.d/docker) in the virtual machine. Line 98: /usr/local/bin/docker -d -D -g "$DOCKER_DIR" -H unix:// $DOCKER_HOST $EXTRA_ARGS --insecure-registry registry.af-sys.com  >> "$DOCKER_LOGFILE" 2>&1 &

Comment: /var/lib/boot2docker/profile is available to set variables such as EXTRA_ARGS, in preference to editing the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following Bryan's note, I added the following to the boot2docker profile:

```
boot2docker ssh -t sudo vi /var/lib/boot2docker/profile

# Insecure Registry
EXTRA_ARGS="--insecure-registry registry.af-sys.com"

boot2docker restart
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Docker for Mac, you can set up some arguments in the UI Preferences:

[image]

For example:

- add Insecure registries
- add Registry mirrors
- change the HTTP proxy settings

[image]